# Something unknown is failing to authenticate and locking my account

Tags: windows-7, windows-authentication

I have a couple of Windows 7 machines and there is a constant authentication failure somewhere. I know this because I get a message "The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to". When I call the IT department, they click a button and I can log on. This is really tedious.

None of my day-to-day resources are unavailable, e.g. mapped network drives, email. I need to know

1. Which machine is initiating the request
2. The specific command which is failing the request
3. The specific network resource to which it's attempting authentication (e.g. hostname, port)

I have cleared all items in the Credentials Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Items #1 and #3 should be accessible to your IT department, presuming they have proper logging tools in place.  Item #2 is a bit more tricky, but will in the end be what you need to resolve the problem.

Generally, issues like this are due to a script or application that attempts to connect to a network resource with some static credentials.  The problem arises when those credentials expire (e.g.: password change) but are not updated in the script or application.

Check all the systems you use or administer for Services or Scheduled Tasks that are set to run with your credentials.  (If you can get items #1 or #3 from your IT department, it will help to greatly narrow the necessary scope of this task.)  Make sure those credentials are updated to your current username/password.  Ideally, you should get these items moved to using a proper "service account" that is not your primary user account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any specific log I can suggest they inspect?

Comment: @Cuadue I'd expect the information should be in the logs on their Domain Controller.